# Displaying Firebase data in UITableView

Tags: swift, firebase

I am very new to the Swift language. I am simply trying to pull business names I have collected in my Firebase and display them on my UITableView

I have tried making several changes. To start, I checked and changed the Firebase permissions so that it allows to be read. Being new to swift, I tried using different functions that come with Firebase CocoaPods.

[A link to a sample of my Firebase setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kAP4.jpg)

```
class businessTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var name = [String]()

    var ref: DatabaseReference!,
    business = [eventStruct]()

    struct eventStruct{
        let sName: String!
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        loadBusinesses()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func loadBusinesses(){
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("name").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]{
                let name = valueDictionary["name"]
                self.business.insert(eventStruct(sName: name) , at: 0)


            }
        })

    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return business.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "businessCell", for: indexPath)

        let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = business[indexPath.row].sName

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: What kind of troubleshooting have you done? Did you step through your code to see what's not working? Is data being loaded from Firebase? Is your dataSource being populated? What's not working?

Comment: I copy and pasted your `func loadBusinesses` into a project and duplicated your structure and it read each business name correctly. How do you know it's not working? Try commenting out the line `self.business` and replace it with a `print(name)`. Each business name printed to console when I did that.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This answer does not solve your problem, see the comment.**

First, you should remove observer when the view controller disappears, so you should hold a reference to the listener:

```swift
class businessTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var handle: DatabaseHandle!

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
    }

    func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        loadBusinesses()
    }

    func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        if let handle = handle {
            ref.removeObserverWithHandle(handle)
        }
    }
```

Take a look at [this post on where to initialize and remove references and listeners](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/best-practices-for-ios-uiviewcontroller_6.html).

Your `valueDictionary` should look something like:

```
   [
        0: ["address": "...", ...],
        1: [...],
        ...,
   ]
```

but you are just doing `valueDictionary["name"]` which doesn't exist.
If you need to get an update when the values in the server updates, you'd probably want to use `.value` not `.childAdded`.
Also, remove all previous values in `business` before the update.
You should:

```swift
    func loadBusinesses() {
        handle = ref.child("name").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            self.business.removeAll()
            for (index, value) in valueDictionary.enumerated() {
                if let name = (value as? [String: String])?["name"] {
                    self.business.insert(eventStruct(sName: name), at: 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: there might be typos.

Comment: There are some issues with this answer and we don't want to send the OP off in the wrong direction. Most importantly, his code works with his structure (try it - I did). Reading a node by .childAdded iterates over each child node, one at a time (0, 1, 2) and the snapshot contains the children; so the */name* node does exist within each child (0/name, 1/name etc). Both .value and .childAdded present data when the server has new data. However, .value presents ALL of the nodes (so iteration is needed), which may be a lot, whereas .childAdded presents just the node that was added.